# Question on order of a group

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a group of order $n$. Let $H=\{a\in G:a=a^{-1}\}$. Then which of the following is true?

$(A)$ If cardinality of $H$ is odd then $n$ must be odd.

$(B)$ The cardinality of $H$ divides $n$.

$(C)$ If the cardinality of $H$ is even then $n$ is odd.

$(D)$ The cardinality of $H$ is a power of 2.

Take $G=S_3$ then we can cancel options B and C.
Take $G=\mathbb Z_3$ then option D gets cancel.

Proof for option $(A)$:

Let $|H|$ be an odd number. If possible assume that $n$ is an even number.

Let $K=\{a\in G: a\notin H\}$ . Then $|K|$ must be an odd number.
Now if $a\in K$ then $a^{-1}\neq a$ also $a^{-1}$ must be in $K$. So we must have even number of elements in $K$,which is a contradiction. Thus our assumption is wrong. Hence $n$ must also be odd.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Your solution to $(A)$ looks okay to me.